# sed delete all after the first period followed by numbers inclusive

Tags: awk, sed, grep, python

```
.bill.sally.foo.bar.1.3.21.3.43.nupkg
```

I want to remove all after the first period (inclusive) followed by numbers so output is:

```
.bill.sally.foo.bar
```

This will be embedded in a `python` script via subroutine

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for both `sed` and `python`, I am giving you `sed`:

```
sed 's/\.[0-9].*//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Within a `python` script:

```
import re

s = '.bill.sally.foo.bar.1.3.21.3.43.nupkg'
result = re.sub(r'\.\d.*', '', s)

print(result)
```

---

It will print:

```
.bill.sally.foo.bar
```